# Don't stop rake task if raise an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have simple rake file.
It imports data from the `.xls` file to the database.
But some of the data is invalid. Then data is invalid rake stop excecuting script.
But I wan to just skip this row and try with the next.

Part of my code:

```
data.each do |row|

username = row[0].slice!(0..2) + row[1].slice!(0..2) + rand(100).to_s
username.downcase
password = "pass1234"
User.create!(
    email: row[2].downcase,
    username: username,
    first_name: row[0],
    last_name: row[1],
    expiration_date: row[3],
    password: password,
    password_confirmation: password)
p 'done'
```

end

The error is about the validation, eg.:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Expiration date must be after 2015-10-27
```

Script is stopped and valid records are not added.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap it in a begin/rescue block.

```
data.each do |row|
  begin 
    username = row[0].slice!(0..2) + row[1].slice!(0..2) + rand(100).to_s
    username.downcase
    password = "pass1234"
    User.create!(
        email: row[2].downcase,
        username: username,
        first_name: row[0],
        last_name: row[1],
        expiration_date: row[3],
        password: password,
        password_confirmation: password)
    p 'done'
  rescue => e
    # log exception or ignore it.
  end 
end
```

*Note that this works because the default rescue is for StandardError. Since ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid < StandardError. It will be 'catched'.*

*You could rescue the specific error first if you only want to do something with those specific errors.*

(For reference also see the API: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Exception.html)